# How to fix ‘AttributeError: cffi library '_constant_time' has no function, constant or global variable named '__spec__'’ error in django”

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, django-2.2

I want to import requests lib (in views.py)to request some information from the other website. but there is a error like title

in ivews.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.http import JsonResponse

from django.core import serializers

import requests

import json
```

> AttributeError: cffi library '_constant_time' has no function,
>   constant or global variable named '**spec**'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/49646/Desktop/auto_order/manage.py", line 21, in 
>   ..... if not isinstance(module, ModuleType) or getattr(module,
>   '**spec**', None) is None: SystemError: 
>   returned a result with an error set

Comment: have you solved this ?

Comment: What version of `cffi` library are you using? In Django, when I am using `bcrypt`, which also requires `cffi` lib. Then, I occurs some errors like this: 


```
AttributeError: cffi library '_bcrypt' has no function, constant or global variable named '__spec__'
```
Later, I upgrade `cffi` lib from 1.11.2 to 1.13.1, then it fixes and works.

Comment: For anyone viewing this thread in the future, just update the ```cffi``` library to the latest version. I also faced this issue with version 1.11.2. I updated to 1.14.0 which is the latest version as of now.

Answer (score 0):

As [@John-Doe notes in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528946/how-to-fix-attributeerror-cffi-library-constant-time-has-no-function-const/68279571?noredirect=1#comment107405131_56528946), upgrading `cffi` to latest version (now 1.14.5) fixes this exact same error. I've personally confirmed this with Django 3.x on MacOS X 10.14.